# Branch view for a file that has been split into multiple files

Tags: branch, perforce, integrate, perforce-branch-spec

I have a large source file in Perforce that has been split up into several smaller files in a branch. I want to create a branch view that can handle this, but perforce (2009.1) only sees the last of the multiple files. For example, I created:

```
p4 integrate //depot/original/huge_file.c //depot/new/huge_file.c
```

Later I split the huge file into smaller ones:

```
p4 integrate //depot/new/huge_file.c //depot/new/small_file_one.c
p4 integrate //depot/new/huge_file.c //depot/new/small_file_two.c
p4 integrate //depot/new/huge_file.c //depot/new/small_file_three.c
```

Then edit each of those (including `//depot/new/huge_file.c`) and submit.

Now I make changes to `//depot/original/huge_file.c` and I want to integrate those changes to `//depot/new`. If I do this manually, it works fine:

```
p4 integrate //depot/original/huge_file.c //depot/new/huge_file.c
p4 integrate //depot/original/huge_file.c //depot/new/small_file_one.c
p4 integrate //depot/original/huge_file.c //depot/new/small_file_two.c
p4 integrate //depot/original/huge_file.c //depot/new/small_file_three.c
```

But I don't want to do that every time I integrate -- this kind of thing belongs in a branch view.

Unfortunately if the branch view includes the same source file multiple times, the subsequent lines override the earlier ones. How can I create a branch view like this:

```
//depot/original/huge_file.c //depot/new/huge_file.c
//depot/original/huge_file.c //depot/new/small_file_one.c
//depot/original/huge_file.c //depot/new/small_file_two.c
//depot/original/huge_file.c //depot/new/small_file_three.c
```

When I integrate using this branch spec, I get only small_file_three.c integrated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was going to suggest that you use an [overlay mapping](http://kb.perforce.com/article/55/mapping-multiple-directories) (a means to force all the lines of the spec to be processed), but a quick perusal of the page put the kibosh on that:

> Overlay mappings are only allowed on
>   client views and do not work with
>   branch views.

It looks like you'll have to script it.  [This page](http://kb.perforce.com/article/239/vss-shared-files-and-perforce) has some more info that might be of use to you (and emphasizes the fact that this can't be done, *"Perforce does not support 1:many file mappings."*).

Comment: Another possible solution, which I have done with Perforce, is to have multiple branch views to specify each of the different new files.  It's clunky, but when I was doing a lot of splitting similar to this, it ended up working fairly well, as you can reuse the same branch specs with different source files.

Answer (score 0):

Just as a matter of interest, but why?

Why not have huge_file.c not in Perforce, and then change your build system to assemble it out of the three smaller, source controlled, source files. Or even just #include them if you wanted real simplicity.

In other words, I'm wondering if your're trying to use the wrong tool for the task you want to do?

Comment: The source file huge_file.c was already in Perforce, and had become a conglomeration of several independent things that really belonged in separate compilation units. I split it up as a way to clean up the source code. Now each of the source files is much smaller and more manageable.

Comment: I should also explain that //depot/original is an old version of the product, and no new development is occurring on that branch, only bug fixes. New development is in //depot/new. Hence the need for integrating between the two in P4.